# I am travelling around England measuring. But what, and why?

Tags: geography, english

I am to travel around England with my pH meter and related equipment. My boss gives me the following instructions as a reminder of where to visit.

D I X Y.

What does this mean, where should I go, and what am I doing?

**Notes**

1. Local knowledge will undoubtedly make this easier for English people but any English speaker can theoretically solve it.
2. England is part of the UK, not all of it. See dark red area of map.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have been tasked with measuring...

> **water quality** of **England's rivers**. (The pH meter will measure their acidity/alkalinity.)

Your boss's 4-letter instructions...

> are the names of 4 English rivers that sound like letters of the alphabet when spoken aloud:
>
>  - The **[Dee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_Dee,_Wales)** can be found very close to the borders of England and Wales, running through Chester.
>
>  - The **Eye** might be the one in [Gloucestershire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_Eye,_Gloucestershire) or the one in [Leicestershire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_Eye,_Leicestershire).
>
>  - The **[Exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_Exe)** flows mainly through Devon, and out to the sea at Exeter.
>
>  - The **[Wye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_Wye)** is the fourth longest river in the UK, another waterway on the Welsh and English border.
>
>  I presume the order given is the order they would like you to visit these rivers.

Comment: Good job the instructions didn't include C, or it could be a long, long trip!

Comment: And the reason why the question specified England rather than Britain or the UK is that there’s also a well-known river Dee in Scotland. And less well-known ones in Cumbria and  Galloway.